# Cannot update mutable instance attributes when __setattr__ and __getattribute__ are overridden in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, getattr, setattr

I have inherited a bunch of legacy code and have run into a bit of a breaking issue. I believe the idea attempted here was to use a containerized cache such as redis to hold certain attributes to be shared across many processes. Apart from whether or not this was the best way to accomplish the task, I stumbled upon something that confused me. If the `__getattribute__` and `__setattr__` methods are overridden as below, mutable instance attributes are not able to be updated. I would expect the changes made to `self.b` to be reflected in the `print()` call but as you can see from the output, only the initial blank dictionary is printed. Stepping through the `self.b["foo"] = "bar"` line shows that a call to `__getattribute__` is made and the correct object is retrieved from the cache but no call to `__setattr__` is made nor does the dictionary seem to update in any way. Anyone have any ideas why this may be?

```
import dill

_reserved_fields = ["this_is_reserved"]

class Cache:
    _cache = {}

    def get(self, key):
        try:
            return self._cache[key]
        except KeyError:
            return None

    def set(self, key, value):
        self._cache[key] = value

    def exists(self, key):
        return key in self._cache


class Class(object):
    def __init__(self, cache):
        self.__dict__['_cache'] = cache
        self.a = 1
        self.a = 2
        print(self.a)
        self.b = dict()
        self.b["foo"] = "bar"  # these changes aren't set in the cache and seem to disappear
        print(self.b)
        self.this_is_reserved = dict()
        self.this_is_reserved["reserved_field"] = "value"  # this updates fine
        print(self.this_is_reserved)

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        try:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, item)
        except AttributeError:
            key = "redis-key:" + item
            if not object.__getattribute__(self, "_cache").exists(key):
                raise AttributeError
            else:
                obj = object.__getattribute__(self, "_cache").get(key)
                return dill.loads(obj)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key in _reserved_fields:
            self.__dict__[key] = value
        elif key.startswith('__') and key.endswith('__'):
            super().__setattr__(key, value)
        else:
            value = dill.dumps(value)
            key = "redis-key:" + key
            self._cache.set(key, value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cache = Cache()
    inst = Class(cache)

    # output
    # 2
    # {}
    # {'reserved_field': 'value'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `self.b["foo"] = "bar"` is *getting* the attribute `b` from self, where `b` is assumed to be a dictionary, and assigning to key `"foo"` in said dictionary. `__setattr__` will only be invoked if you assign *directly* to b, e.g., `self.b = {**self.b, 'foo': 'bar'}` (in Python 3.5+ for the dictionary update).

Without adding hooks in your stored objects to trigger a cache save on their `__setattr__`, and their sub-objects `__settattr__`, etc..., you could add a way to explicitly trigger a cache update (meaning user code needs to be aware of the cache), or avoid mutating the fields except through direct assignment.

Sorry about your luck ;).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are re-implementing the shelve module without implementing object writeback.

When:

```
self.b = dict()
```

occurs the `__setattr__` stores a pickled dictionary in the cache:

Then when:

```
self.b["foo"] = "bar"
```

The `__getattribute__` unpickles the dictionary and returns it. Then Python sets that dictionary's foo key to bar. Then it throws away the dictionary.